# Game with a shopper on a bridge

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm trying to remember the name of game I played when I was new to this hobby.   I played this game in 2004 so it would have been released before then.

The game board involved a bridge.  Players built shops on this bridge.  Their was a customer piece that would visit shops and spend money.

The mechanic was players had cards (I think numbered in multiples on 10 up to 100).  Players all simultaneously selected a card face down.   The customer would go to the shop with the lowest unique bid.  However the player who won the bid could then sell the right to have the customer come to their shop to another player.  eg if I won it with 20 I could say to a player who bid 90 that I will let the shopper come to them if they gave my 50.  I think players had to play through there whole hand before getting the cards back.

I recalled the shops being chunky coloured pieces in the player colours that were placed either side of the bridge and a the shopper would only go to a shop that was in front of them.  I don't recall specific rules for that or how new shops were built on the board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ponte Vecchio](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/324/ponte-vecchio)?  According to BoardGameGeek:

> The "rich gentleman" has money burning a hole in his purse. He also
>   likes to spend the day ambling back and forth along the Old Bridge
>   (Ponte Vecchio), spending wherever he stops.